# Wait for state to update when using hooks

Tags: reactjs

How do I wait for state to update using Hooks. When I submit my form I need to check if `termsValidation` is false before running some additional code. If the state has just changed it doesn't pick up on this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Signup() {
  const [terms, setTerms] = useState('');
  const [termsValidation, setTermsValidation] = useState(false);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!terms) {
      setTermsValidation(true);
    } else {
      setTermsValidation(false);
    }

    if (!termsValidation) {
      console.log('run something here');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" checked={terms} />

        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Sign up
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 38):

The `useState` hook is asynchronous but it doesn't have a callback api like `setState` does. If you want to wait for a state update you need a `useEffect` hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Signup() {
  const [terms, setTerms] = useState('');
  const [termsValidation, setTermsValidation] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!termsValidation) {
      console.log('run something here');
    }
  }, [termsValidation]);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!terms) {
      setTermsValidation(true);
    } else {
      setTermsValidation(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" checked={terms} />

        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Sign up
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just be careful with a  loop. It can exceed the update depth and render infinitely

Comment: I'm facing this exact same problem and this answer is correct but oh god how awful the code looks!

Answer (score 22):

Changing state like `setTermsValidation` is asynchronous action which means it's not immediate and the program does not wait for it. It fires and forgets. Hence, when you call `setTermsValidation(true)` the program will continue run the next block instead of waiting termValidation to change to be true. That's why termsValidation will still have the old value.

You can just do this

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!terms) {
      setTermsValidation(true);
    } else {
      setTermsValidation(false);
      // assuming you want to run something when termsvalidation turn to false
      console.log('run something here');
    }
}
```

Or ideally use hooks [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!termsValidation) {
      console.log('run something here');
    }
}, [termsValidation]);
```

However, be careful because useEffect also runs on initial render.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget useRef as a possibility in situations like this - useState and useEffect have their place of course, but your logic to track and manage the state can be a bit of a pain, as well as causing probable unnecessary re-renders of your component (when that state doesn't form part of the render output). As an example from the OP:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Signup() {
  const [terms, setTerms] = useState('');
  const termsValidation = useRef(false);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!terms && !termsValidation.current) {
      termsValidation.current = true;
      console.log('run something here');
      termsValidation.current = false; // when its finished running
    }
 }

  return (
    <div> etc
  );
}
```